# How do I display all elements from json array

Tags: vuejs2

I am having issues display json array from api. How do I display json array in html?

I tried

```
<div v-for="item in items>
{{item.Food.name}}
</div>
```

and I tried `item in Food, then item.name`

and

```
item.Food[index].name
```

But it displays only one element, not all.

Json:

```
{
   "Food":[
      {
         "name":"Banana",
         "type":"Fruits",
    
      },
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template v-if="items && items.Food">    
   <div v-for="item in items.Food>
   {{item.name}}
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I just want to ask which variable is your JSON Array equal to ? Is your items equal to [] ? I updated answer hope this works.